# Installing Ruby on AIX

Tags: ruby, rvm, aix

What are some less painful ways to install Ruby on AIX?

I found out that using RVM to install Ruby might be the best option. However, installing RVM itself seems like really maddening. I found an article from IBM website on how to install RVM but there are so many prerequisites for it that I feel like it will take me days to get all that stuff installed and get working:

> However, RVM does have some prerequisites. Before you continue, check your system and be sure that you have the bash, git, tar, curl, gunzip, and bunzip2 utilities installed locally. In addition, your system must have the Readline, IConv, zLib, OpenSSL, and Autoconf packages to build the Ruby interpreters. You must have the Bash shell to install RVM, but you can use RVM with the Z shell version 4.3.5 or higher after RVM is installed. git is required to automatically update RVM, and this is explained shortly.

I looked up git and it has at least 10 prerequisites (includes Python which I know has tons of prerequisites as well).

Is there any way I can install all those prerequisites in once?

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-manage-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this done a couple of years ago (ruby 2.0.0).
I installed by compiling it from source as I did not have root access and wanted to install it in an afs directory anyway.

Here is my SO question and the my answer to my own question:
[How do I configure ruby to compile in 64 bit mode on AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471194/how-do-i-configure-ruby-to-compile-in-64-bit-mode-on-aix)

Here are some notes I had on how to do this as well.
if I recall using /usr/bin/ksh93 provided a huge speedup, I for get the details as to why, but using the default ksh installed on our servers was painfully slow.

```
export LIBPATH=/usr/lib
export CONFIG_SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh93
export OBJECT_MODE=64


./configure --enable-shared  --enable-load-relative  --disable-install-doc --prefix=your_install_path_here --exec-prefix=your_install_path_here/aix CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-maix64 -mminimal-toc" CXX="g++" CXXFLAGS="-maix64 -mminimal-toc" NM="nm -X64" AR="ar -X64" LDFLAGS="-maix64 -Wl,-bbigtoc" EXTLDFLAGS="-maix64 -Wl,-bbigtoc" DLDFLAGS="-shared -maix64 -Wl,-bbigtoc"
```

I would like to install a new version but this was really painful at the time.

**Update**

Another less painful way to use ruby on AIX is to install [JRuby](http://jruby.org/).  I have done that as well, and make use of it for gui's via [SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/).  The biggest downside with JRuby is that it has to spin up a JVM, which takes some time.  This is not a big deal for long running programs, but for short scripts it can be noticeable

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to Unix system. After ./configure... Should I call "make" and then "make install"? Where should I place the source code though?

Comment: I have Ruby installed on Ubuntu, would it still work if I copied it over to AIX server?

Comment: You would download the ruby.tar.gz file, use gunzip to create the ruby.tar, then tar to extract the tar file into a directory.  the --prefix and --exec-prefix on the configure invocation determine where the compiled code will be placed. So the source code can be extracted anywhere you like.  Once it is extracted you cd into that directory and run the ./configure, followed by make and make install.

Comment: I don't think you can copy it from Ubuntu, particularly if the Ubuntu install is on another server.  AIX runs on POWER processors,  your Ubuntu install is probably on an intel processor.

Comment: What about dependenies? Is there a simple option to install them all?

Comment: I copied Ruby from Ubuntu and running "ruby -v" showed the version. but when I try to install a gem: "ERROR:  Loading install (LoadError) load failed - /opt/freeware/lib/ruby/2.0.0/powerpc-aix5.1.0.0/openssl.so. Please issue below command for detailed reasons: /usr/sbin/execerror ruby "2  /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so" "50 /usr/lib/libcrypto.a libcrypto.so.1.0.1" "52 libcrypto.so.1.0.1" "2  /opt/freeware/lib/ruby/2.0.0/powerpc-aix5.1.0.0/openssl.so" "50  /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.so" ERROR:  While executing gem .. (NoMethodError) undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I don't think there are too many hard dependencies,  the config process go thru and checks to make sure everything it needs to compile is available, and if any of the optional dependencies are available it will configure those as well.  These would be things like the tk bindings for example.  BTW, another option which may or may not be acceptable to you is to install jruby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90899/discussion-between-darkpool-and-npn).