# Would AIX 7 support Capistrano 3?

Tags: capistrano

Would AIX 7 support Capistrano v3.4.0 (or above) and its dependent scripting tools such as Gem, Ruby, Rake, etc...? and if it does, where could one find a list of supported versions for the dependent scripting tools?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Capistrano README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#requirements), you need Ruby 2.0 or higher. All of Capistrano's gem dependencies are automatically installed when you run `gem install capistrano`, assuming that your Ruby 2.0 environment is working.

That said, installing Ruby on AIX seems challenging. You may have to compile it from source: [Installing Ruby on AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790755/installing-ruby-on-aix/32793763) .

This assumes of course that you want to deploy *from* AIX (i.e. run the `cap` command on an AIX machine) as opposed to deploying *to* AIX (using a Mac, PC, or Linux machine to deploy to an AIX server). If you want to do the latter, you should be fine: Capistrano has no requirements for the server other than sshd.

Comment: Thank you kindly. We'd probably request a Linux then. We basically want to use Capistrano from a "Util" host to build from SVN deploy-able artifacts such as (IBM) IIB .bar files and Java/J2EE .jar/.war/.ear files and deploy them to remote hosts - some which would run IIB services, others J2EE ones. The Infrastructure group requested us (in RM - Release Management) to use AIX for this 'Util" host, but we have some reservations on AIX. So your answer would help us to give them the needed information. Thanks again.

Comment: Correction: They only suggested to us, not _requested us_.